# Integration to get live data from GoogleSheet to MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

Below code is working fine and importing the data from Google Sheet Web link.

Below code is additionaly add the first row and column whereas that is not available in Google Sheets.

The solution i am looking for is to remove the first row and first column from the Excel sheet because these are not available in google sheets. I want to copy the exact things which are availble on Sheet.

or is there any way to make it automate that i would not have to run the macro to get the updated result from google sheet. It should update it automatically as Excel Byval fucntion works.

Hope someone can help me and I really appreciate your effort of reading my questions!

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRv93GZ5W-yFbfSzApjQs2d3N4RQte4E1lKKMpe_Ykqc2S6wMqqvq5I8qv8hLntJ_70Eg0ktscwaypH/pubhtml", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "0,1"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Someone can please solve the issue?

Comment: @Rubén can you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.

https://trumpexcel.com/vba-delete-row-excel/

Also, you can auto-run an Excel Macro when a Workbook opens.  Here is a simple example.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ' Put your code here
End Sub
```